# How can I change who is the leader of my party?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1

I really want to swap Compa out for someone else, as she is relatively weak when attacking and I usually end up having her die really fast. Problem is, she is apparently my party leader for some reason, and I can't find a way to swap her out.

How can I change who my party leader is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget which, but Triangle or Start (possibly both?) changes party leader to the highlighted character on the Party menu (or the top level of the main menu) and yeah, you can't change the leader out of the party without switching.

On PC it should be whatever button activates skills in the PC version (triangle/top button) or whatever pauses the game.

Comment: Which one did it end up being?